# Disabling HTML on Comments

Tags: wordpress

I've been researching for the past few hours, trying to find a way to disable HTML in WordPress comments.  So far this one consistently appeared on top of Google search results numerous times:

```
// This will occur when the comment is posted
function plc_comment_post( $incoming_comment ) {

// convert everything in a comment to display literally
$incoming_comment['comment_content'] = htmlspecialchars($incoming_comment['comment_content']);

// the one exception is single quotes, which cannot be #039; because WordPress marks it as spam
$incoming_comment['comment_content'] = str_replace( "'", '&apos;',         $incoming_comment['comment_content'] );

return( $incoming_comment );
}

// This will occur before a comment is displayed
function plc_comment_display( $comment_to_display ) {

// Put the single quotes back in
$comment_to_display = str_replace( '&apos;', "'", $comment_to_display );

return $comment_to_display;
```

This code did not work with the latest version of WordPress. I also found many more codes that again, did not work.  So how would one go about disabling HTML in WordPress 3.6 (the latest version) comments?

Comment: How old are the articles you've found that code on?

Comment: Has the WordPress API changed in the meantime?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson not sure but i found a solution to this problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This removed the ability for users to post HTML (but not links for some strange reason) within comments:

`add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_specialchars' );`

This removed the ability for users to post links within comments:

`remove_filter('comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9);`

Comment: add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses' ); has got links covered too.

Comment: And you add add_filter('get_comment_author_link', array('Comments_Cleaner', 'RemoveHTML'));
and no spammer will spam you with links :)

Comment: This answer disables HTML by replacing HTML code with plaintext. Whereas the answer by Jothi disables HTML by *removing* the HTML code (e.g. `<b>hello</b>` becomes `hello`).

Answer (score 4):

To disable HTML tags in comments, put the following code into your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('comment_text', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses');
add_filter('comment_text_rss', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses');
add_filter('comment_excerpt', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses');
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do, I just wanted to disable them from COMMENTS not my whole website in general.

Comment: This code disables HTML by *removing* the HTML code (e.g. `<b>hello</b>` becomes `hello`). The answer by Dyck disables HTML by replacing HTML code with plaintext.